# Horror Episode #5: Hats and Cloves

Tags: knowledge, geography

A row of four hats is seen sitting on a desk through the window of a noble Victorian Era clothing store. Before you can even prepare yourself as you walk in to get a closer look, you are immediately greeted by a strong unmistakable smell hanging from the wooden poles. Sure enough, there is garlic all over the place.

The owner of the store says that there is something fishy about the country of origin of one of the four hats, since they were all sent anonymously. Almost as if there was a secret being held from the store owner herself. There were little strange quotes that came with each of the hats and they are as follows.

Top Hat- Can a dam in my hidden country truly outstand this posh presence?

Bowler- This country is true love...

Fedora- Cloth tatters away in my origin country...

Boater- I could be anywhere other than the countries of my fellow three. It doesn't matter. Don't worry... but a stellar number with symbolism is with my country.

Which hat caused the garlic to come out and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Top Hat- Can a dam in my hidden country truly outstand this posh presence?*

> "**Can a da**m in my hidden country" ... this must be CANADA.

*Bowler- This country is true love...*

> France and Italy are traditionally seen as romantic countries, but I'm going to gp with ROMANIA - its name is almost "romance", and it would explain the garlic because vampires famously come from Romania.

*Fedora- Cloth tatters away in my origin country...*

> Not sure about this one. Maybe some wordplay with "Cloth tatters"?

*Boater- I could be anywhere other than the countries of my fellow three. It doesn't matter. Don't worry... but a stellar number with symbolism is with my country.*

> The "stellar number with symbolism" probably means some symbolic collection of stars on the national flag. Lots of flags have stars, and most of these probably have *some* sort of symbolism, but I'm going to go with the UNITED STATES since the number of stars corresponds symbolically to the number of states.

Why the garlic?

> The bowler, as explained above.